# Insert text into DIV itself with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have an issue with my code, I need to know how can I inject some code inside the jQuery as below in part of JS.

```
 function d(a, d, f, g, h, l, q) {
      m(d, g);
      var t = null,
      u = "div"; 
      d.tag && (u = d.tag);

      switch (d.t) {
          case "rect":
          case "ellipse":
          case "canvas":
          case "group":
          t = s(u, a, d, f, h, l,g, q);
      }
}
```

**

`u="div";` in JQuery automatically generated the below code
   in source in browser I mean in source of page like below

**

```
<div id="Stage_Ellipse"></div>
```

How can I inject some code inside of div that mean put some text inside the DIV itself for example I need to put the text (code-injected-here) like below

```
<div code-injected-here id="Stage_Ellipse" ></div>
```

Comment: This is not clear to know what you want to do. `how can i injected some code inside the jQuery` and `<div code-injected-here id="Stage_Ellipse" >` does not make sense at all to me. What's your starting point ? What's your expected result ? What did you tried ?

Comment: I guess you are looking for setting data `.attr` just like @name3anad answered.

Comment: Simpel as it is the jQuery code above rendering the  <div id="Stage_Ellipse"></div> in source page what i need only some change in jQuery side to render it with insert code-injected-here to DIV it self that all

Answer (score 2):

if its ok for you to have

```
<div code-injected-here='' id='Stage_Ellipse'></div>
```

you can:

```
$('#Stage_Ellipse').attr('code-injected-here', '');
```

Comment: Its mean to add your code into u = "div";  in jQuery ? because i have no idea how to put.

Answer (score 0):

You can't put code in that place,you can use the method like @name3anad said.

if you want to show code in screen you can use `<code>` or `<pre>`

if you want to bind event in div , you should write it in `<script>` :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function d(a, d, f, g, h, l, q) {
          m(d, g);
          var t = null,
          u = document.getElementById('Stage_Ellipse'); //change this
          d.tag && (u = d.tag);

          switch (d.t) {
              case "rect":
              case "ellipse":
              case "canvas":
              case "group":
              t = s(u, a, d, f, h, l,g, q);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Stage_Ellipse automatically generated by the software what i need only to add some text near to DIV

Answer (score -1):

**$('#Stage_Ellipse').html("Your text here...");**

The above code will set the content which you wish to set for the div.